# ¿cual es el problema de este codigo en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy armando una web en react y soy nuevo, estoy armandolo con firebase con su base de datos firestore, realizo la captura de la información a través de un useEffect y lo dejo separado en tres userState. pero al momento de colocarlo en el return y ocupar un .map me dice que la función map no es una función.

me puede decir que hago mal

Gracias

comparto código

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import '../App.css';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { db } from "../firebase/firebase";
import { doc, collection, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore"


const Order = (() => {
  const { orderID } = useParams();
  const [order, setOrder] = useState({});
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const ventasCollection = collection(db, 'ventas');
    const referenceDoc = doc(ventasCollection, orderID);
    getDoc(referenceDoc)
    .then(result => {
        const order = {
          id: result.id,
          ...result.data(),
        }
        setOrder(order);
        setPersons(order.form);
        setItems(order.items);
    }).catch(error => console.err);
  }, [orderID]);

  console.log(order, persons, items);
  return(
      <>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <h2>Orden de Envio </h2>
            <div className="col s12 right-align">
              {orderID}
            </div>
            {
              persons.map((person, index) => {
                return(
                  <div className="col s12" key={index}>
                    <h2>person.phone</h2>
                  </div>
                )
              })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </>     
  );    
});

export default Order;
```

Comment: Puedes logear el arreglo `persons` para ver qué contiene?

Comment: coloco un console.log y me da los datos :{country: 'Chile', email: 'jpgrover@mounkey.cl', nombre: 'Juan Pablo Grover Pinto', zip: '5502899', phone: '+56982657064', …}
address: "Jose Manuel Balmaceda 15"
city: "Puerto Montt"
country: "Chile"
email: "jpgrover@mounkey.cl"
nombre: "Juan Pablo Grover Pinto"
phone: "+56982657064"
state: "Los Lagos"
zip: "5502899"

Comment: lo mas raro que coloco un items.map y si me manda los datos

Comment: Pero eso no es un arrray. Es un objeto. Los objetos no tienen la función `.map` Por eso es el error

Comment: hago un foreach y me sale lo mismo

Comment: Por eso, un objeto no puede ser iterado, porque no es una lista. Solo las listas pueden ser iteradas por `.map` o `.foreach`. Qué es lo que necesitas hacer? Por favor [edit] to pregunta y agrega lo que necesitas lograr. Lee [ask] y [example]

Comment: Lo que necesito es visualizar el objeto entero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problema

El problema es que estás intentando usar la función [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) en un objeto y no en un array.

Esto no es posible debido a que los [objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) de javascript no son iterables como lo son los arreglos.

### Solución

La solución es usar directamente el objeto en el componente y no iterarlo:

```javascript
return(
      <>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <h2>Orden de Envio </h2>
            <div className="col s12 right-align">
              {orderID}
            </div>

            <div className="col s12">
               <h2>persons.phone</h2> <!-- Usamos la variable persons directamente si tratar de iterarla ya que es un objeto y no un array -->
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </>     
  );    
});
```

Como comentario, te recomiendo cambiar el nombre de la variable `persons` a `person` en singular ya que esto es lo que puede causarte confusión.

Conceptualmente la variable `persons` no tiene un nombre correcto ya que no contiene muchas personas (una lista) si no que contiene los datos de solo 1 persona.

Comment: Gracias, estoy armandolo asi

Comment: Si la respuesta solucionó tu problema considera marcarla como respuesta aceptada. Saludos!

Comment: Como hago para marcarlo jajajaj soy renuevo

Comment: Te debería salir un simbolo de check a la izquierda de la respuesta. Abajo de donde se vota la respuesta si mal no recuerdo

Comment: Listo compalero y muchas gracias por tu explicacion